# Does Int32.TryParse(String, Int32) alter the int argument on failure?

Tags: .net, tryparse

Out of interest, is it safe to assume that if `Int32.TryParse(String, Int32)` fails, then the int argument will remain unchanged? For example, if I want my integer to have a default value, which would be wiser?

```
int type;
if (!int.TryParse(someString, out type))
    type = 0;
```

OR

```
int type = 0;
int.TryParse(someString, out type);
```

Comment: Anyone trying to understand the code will wonder the same thing.

Comment: Since it's an `out` parameter, it *must* be assigned before `TryParse` return (unless it throws an exception).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) has the answer:

> contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent to the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I did not see that part.

Answer (score 7):

`TryParse` will set it to `0`.

Since it's an `out` parameter, it wouldn't be possible for it to return without setting the value, even on failure.

Answer (score 2):

TryParse sets the result to 0 before doing anything else. So you should use your first example to set a default value.

Answer (score 1):

If it fails, it returns false and sets type to zero. This would be wisest, as a result:

```
int type;

if (int.TryParse(someString, out type)) 
  ; // Do something with type
else 
  ; // type is set to zero, do nothing
```